# Draw ROC curve in python using confusion matrix only

Tags: python, roc, confusion-matrix

I need to draw ROC curve using confusion matrix only. Actually my system was crashed ( every information was lost), therefore I am not getting data. I have only values of confusion matrix. I know how to create ROC curve (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html), but not getting any clue how to draw from confusion matrix.
Please help me in this regards.

Comment: Do you have one confusion matrix, or the confusion matrices at all thresholds?

Comment: I have only one confusion matrix getting after executing naive Bayes model

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't build a ROC curve from a single contingency matrix.

A ROC curve shows how the sensitivity and specificity vary as you change the decision threshold. In order to do that, it is necessary to calculate these values at *all possible thresholds* (at least those where the values step).

A contingency matrix reports the performance of *one specific threshold*. You can calculate sensitivity and specificity from it, but for a single threshold only. The information regarding the other thresholds has been lost, and therefore you cannot build the ROC curve.